# How to use react-query to replace context

Tags: typescript, react-query

I read [an article on using react-query as a state manager](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager) and I am now trying to replace a context in my app with react-query (version 4).

Previously, I created a context with `useContext()` that stored a **user account** object for the logged-in user. I used react-query to fetch this data, and then `useReducer()` to modify the account object.  However, I realized this is a mess and the relevant data is in react-query anyway, so I should get rid of the context and reducer and just use react-query directly (I am generating the user account object in the query that I make with react-query).

I generate the user account object in a custom hook:

```
function useUser(): UseQueryResult<User, Error> {
  const query = getInitialUserUrl;
  const platform = usePlatformContext();
  return useQuery<User, Error>(
    queryKeyUseUser,
    async () => {
      const data = await fetchAuth(query);
      if (didQueryReturnData(data)) {
        return new User(platform, data[0]);
      }
      return new User(platform);
    },
    {
      refetchOnReconnect: 'always',
      refetchInterval: false,
    },
  );
}

export default useUser;
```

Now I have a mutation where I verify the user's email address (old way using context):

```
const useMutationVerifyEmail = (): UseMutationResult<RpcResponseEmailVerify, Error, FormEmailVerifyInput> => {
  const { userObject } = useUserContext();

  return useMutation(
    (data: FormEmailVerifyInput) => verifyEmail(userObject.id, data.validation_code),
    },
  );
};
```

I tried to replace the call to context with a direct call to `useUser()`:

```
const useMutationVerifyEmail = (): UseMutationResult<RpcResponseEmailVerify, Error, FormEmailVerifyInput> => {
  const { data: userObject } = useUser();

  return useMutation(
    (data: FormEmailVerifyInput) => verifyEmail(userObject.id, data.validation_code),
    },
  );
};
```

However, TypeScript complains that `Object is possibly 'undefined'` for `userObject`.  I'm not sure why, because as far as I understand, `useUser()` always returns a `User` object.

How can I update my custom hook to return a `User` object so that I can use it instead of context?

**UPDATE**

I can wrap my `useUser()` hook in another hook:

```
function useUserObject() {
  const { data: userObject } = useUser();
  if (userObject instanceof User) {
    return userObject;
  }
  throw new Error('Failed to get account info!');
}
```

And then I can do `const userObject = useUserObject()` to get the user account object... but is this really the optimal way?  Do I need to create a custom hook for a custom hook just to use my user objects like I do with `useContext()?`

Comment: Have you tried narrowing by checking `if(userObject)`? Your hooks return type includes the possibility of an error.

Comment: @morganney In `useMutationVerifyEmail`, I can check `if (userObject instanceof User)` to ensure the object is defined as you point out.  But I'm trying to find a way to use `useUser()` without having to check if the result is in fact a `User` object every time.  I call `useUser()` about 50 times in the app, and checking if the object is really there each time is a lot of boilerplate.  I'm already catching errors in an [error boundary](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-error-handling) so I'm hoping there's a way to refactor my code to avoid checking each time.

Comment: Create a wrapper that makes the types more explicit if you don't want to deal with ts narrowing. Maybe this guide can help you https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2021/01/03/strongly-typing-react-query-s-usequeries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wrote the article you've mentioned in your question.

It is not guaranteed that `useQuery` returns data when you call it, because data could not be fetched yet *or* fetching could have failed.

Now you might guarantee this in your app because you only call the hook when data has already been fetched - but TypeScript doesn't know that.

As stated at the end of the article, this is a tradeoff. What it gives you is that each hook is self-contained. If you call `useMutationVerifyEmail` in a place where you don't have a user object yet for whatever reason, it will go and try to fetch it.

There are various ways to "work around / with" that issue / limitation:

1. You can ignore it and use a type assertion / the bang operator (!)

```
const useMutationVerifyEmail = (): UseMutationResult<RpcResponseEmailVerify, Error, FormEmailVerifyInput> => {
  const { data: userObject } = useUser();

  return useMutation(
    (data: FormEmailVerifyInput) => verifyEmail(userObject!.id, data.validation_code),
  );
};
```

This might err at runtime if you move the component that uses this hook to a place where a user isn't available, but it's fine if you know that this is the case :)

2. You can check inside the mutationFn as an invariant, and make the mutation error if there is no user:

```
const useMutationVerifyEmail = (): UseMutationResult<RpcResponseEmailVerify, Error, FormEmailVerifyInput> => {
  const { data: userObject } = useUser();

  return useMutation(
    async (data: FormEmailVerifyInput) => {
      if (!userObject) {
        throw new Error("no user available")
      }
      return verifyEmail(userObject.id, data.validation_code)
    },
  );
};
```

3. you can move the `useUser` call out of your custom mutation hook and just make the userId part of the input that is passed to the mutation.

```
const useMutationVerifyEmail = (): UseMutationResult<RpcResponseEmailVerify, Error, FormEmailVerifyInput> => {
  return useMutation(
    ({ id, ...data} : FormEmailVerifyInput & { id: number }) => verifyEmail(id, data.validation_code),
  );
};
```

Then, the component can call `useQuery`, maybe return `null`, a loading spinner or an error if there is no user, or you can disable the button that triggers the mutation as long as there is no user.

4. You can take a step back and keep your context, but populate it with data from `useQuery`:

```
const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { data } = useUser()

  if (data.isLoading) return "loading ..."
  if (data.isError) return "error"

  return <UserContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
}
```

I might have to write about this pattern some more, because it is *not* state syncing / duplication. It is also *not* managing state with react context. All it does is distribute data from react-query via react-context. `data` is guaranteed to be defined when you read it through `useContext()`, so it takes away the undefined checks.

It will also always give you the "latest" data of react-query, because you still have your subscription via `useQuery` - just further up the tree. Context consumers will be notified of changes because the `value` updates.

Now there are tradeoffs to this as well, namely:

- You cannot do partial subscriptions anymore via `select`, because react-context has no selectors.
- If you do this with multiple Providers, you risk getting into waterfall fetches: fetching the user "blocks" the rest of the app, because it doesn't render `children` until the user is fetched. That's why user is defined when accessing it in children (which is desired), but it will also block all other fetches that would happen in the children.

I've done this before with something like an `EssentialDataProvider`. It triggers a bunch of useQuery calls, like user and stack related information that we need everywhere in the app - so it doesn't make sense to render the app without it. We then distribute it via context so that we don't have to null check it everywhere. We also prefetch these queries on the server.

It's a good tool to have at your disposal, but as everything, it has pros and cons :)

Comment: So react-context is just for null-check? why can't we just have a custom hook for that purpose instead? @tkdodo Because custom hook = share logic. context = share logic + share state. But the "share state" part is done by react-query already, can we just create a custom hook for the remaining share logic purpose? The "share logic" here is null check.

Comment: yes I thought about this as well. You don't have to use context for this. A custom `useUserMandatory` or something hook that just throws if you have no user in the cache works as well. It would also allow `select` so this is a nice benefit if you need it. The context might just be a way to communicate to developer that this only works within a context Provider - you'd expect a custom query-hook to work everywhere. But it's still a good solution, too

Answer (score 2):

The reason TS complains is because the types for react-query do make your user object `undefined`. In full details, the query has states:

```
export type QueryStatus = 'loading' | 'error' | 'success'
```

and it uses unions to, in short, make sure that when your query is in loading or error state (with the exception of refetch error), the `data` from the query is `undefined`, very simplified it looks like this:

```
type QueryObserverResult = {
  status: 'success',
  data: TData
} | {
  status: 'error',
  data: undefined
} | {
  status: 'loading',
  data: undefined
}
```

Since your use case is to use error boundary and rely on `user` being set, an approach here is to cast the `useUser` return value.

```
function useUser(): DefinedUseQueryResult<User, Error> {
  ...
  ...
  return useQuery(...) as DefinedUseQueryResult<User, Error>
}
```